# Magento promotion rule disappear in magento 1.9..0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I've created a promotion rule in magento, after midnight thats promotion have disappear, someone know this problem?

Comment: Have your cron job set up to run cron.sh or cron.php every 15 minutes?

Comment: What do you mean by "disappear"?